# Replacing repeated consecutive characters with X

Tags: mips

I have some trouble with my code.

I need this in/output on the console.

---

Input String : aaabcccdeefggg

Input char: X

Replace:XXXbXXXdXXfXXX   <--I want this output

But i get this output-->XXabXXcdXefXXg

I dont know where the bug is, i am searching for hours for this bug.

```
.data
    enterString:        .asciiz "Input String > "
    enterChar:      .asciiz "Input char> "
    changedString:      .asciiz "\nReplace: "
    numberOfAdditions:  .asciiz "\Total Replaces: "
    userInput:              .space 555
.text
main:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, enterString
    syscall

    li  $v0, 8
    la  $a0, userInput
    li  $a1, 554
    syscall

    li $v0,4
    la $a0,enterChar
    syscall

    li $v0,12
    syscall
    move $t5,$v0            # $t0 = character to be replaced

    li  $t0, 0
    li  $t1, 1
    j   findDoubleCharacters
findDoubleCharacters:
    lbu $s0, userInput( $t0 )
    lbu $s1, userInput( $t1 )
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1
    addi    $t1, $t1, 1
    beq $s0, $s1, found
    beq $s1, 0, end
    j   findDoubleCharacters
found:
    subi    $t0, $t0, 1
    subi    $t1, $t1, 1
    sb  $t5, userInput($t0)          
    addi    $s2, $s2, 1
    j findDoubleCharacters
end:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, changedString

    syscall
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, userInput

    syscall
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, numberOfAdditions
    syscall

    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $s2
    syscall
...
```

Comment: This program is small enough that you can step through it line-by-line in a debugger. As you yourself noted, you have a problem in that the third `a` is not changed to `X`. The third `a` is when t0 = 2 and t1 = 3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I just can not figure out how I should change the values ​​so that I come to the right solution. 
I added "subi $t1, $t1, 1" in line 34 but the programm crashes than.

Comment: Right now, your program replaces the character if it matches the next character, but that misses the last character in the sequence. You'll have to rethink your algorithm.